# Integrate Storm with Ambari in Ubuntu 14

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-storm, ambari

I install Storm and Ambari UI in a Ubuntu machine.

But now I want to join the Storm with ambari UI. Is there any tutorial? anyone have tips?

**Note**: I have just installed on the virtual machine the Storm, Kafka and Ambari server (default).
I know that there is a VM NortonWorks with these pre-installed services, but the idea is to install on a virgin machine.

thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to manage and monitor Storm through Ambari? If so then you must provision Storm through Ambari. You can do this by logging into the ambari UI then clicking the actions buttons and select 'Add Service'. Follow the service installation wizard to install Storm. During this process you will be able to configure Storm to your needs. Storm is available in HDP versions 2.1 and higher.

Comment: I still have no associated cluster. So it does not show this option.
it is possible to set up a local cluster in ambari?

Comment: Yes. That's one of ambaris main purposes to 'provision' a cluster. After you install ambari-server, start it. Then access the ambari web ui and it will walk you through the process of creating a cluster. You should look at the HDP documentation.